# Expected Behavior of search.highlight - Each token surrounded by tag or multiple tokens surrounded by one tag?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

My team is a little confused by the search highlights coming out of the Azure Search results when selecting `highlight=fieldX`.

When searching for a phrase on simple syntax by using double quotes in the search parameter, when observing the results coming out of the `search.highlights` section, some believes it is not searching for the entire phrase, but instead is surfacing results that contain some if not all the tokens in the phrase.

For example: `search="quick brown"&highlight=content` might result in

```
{"@odata.context": "https://az-srch-example.search.windows.net/indexes('example')/$metadata#docs(*)",
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 0.683709,
        "@search.highlights": {
            "content": [
                "The <em>quick</em> <em>brown</em> fox jumped over the lazy dog."
            ]
        },
        "id": "abcexample123"
    }
]}
```

It's perceived that we may be receiving results that search for "quick" and "brown" independently.

**Is there any syntax for merging the search highlights for when the search results are contiguous or are a phrase?**

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any syntax for merging the search highlights for when the search results are contiguous or are a phrase?

In short **No**.

In Azure Search we use Lucene's Postings Highlighter. Highlighting happens after the matched documents are identified. So, the Postings Highlighter takes each document matched, **splits it into sentences a looks for sentences that matched the query terms best (ignoring term positions)**, that's why you see all phrase terms highlighted independently.

Unfortunately there is no way to customize this behavior at the moment. You could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/32661961-implement-other-highlighters) to promote the feature to be achieved.

Comment: Joey's response is spot on. I would like to emphasize onthe fact that during the querying phase, only the documents having the specified phrase are matched. It's only at the post-query highlighting phase that it looks for terms to highlight the sentences in the document. In other words, even if each term gets highlighted independently, there shouldn't be a case where only some of the terms from the original phrase get highlighted leaving out others.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you so much for the guidance on this.  So, this **is expected** behavior and it's still searching for the phrase but the way to document is chopped up causes it to highlight each token separately.  Got it.  Thank you!